# Is there a way I can avoid using GoTo in this situation?

Tags: vba, ms-access, goto

So I've got a sub (triggered by a command button) which runs a process that seems quite time-consuming (between 5 and 20 seconds, dependant on the machine and how co-operative our network is feeling). To make it clear to the user that stuff is happening that they can't see I change the mouse pointer to an hourglass then change it back when the sub exits, regardless of the reason for the exit.

With that in mind my code looks something like this (illustrative example, not actual code):

```
Private Sub cmdDoTheThing_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdDoTheThing

    Screen.MousePointer = 11 'Hourglass/Equivalent

    'Check all data is available to Do The Thing
    If Not MyModule.ThingIsDoable(Me.PrimaryKey) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot Do The Thing, more preliminary things must be done first."
        GoTo Exit_cmdDoTheThing
    End If

    'Try to Do The Thing (function returns false on failure)
    If Not MyModule.DoTheThing(Me.PrimaryKey) Then
        MsgBox "Processing of The Thing failed."
        GoTo Exit_cmdDoTheThing
    End If

    '...
    'Stuff here I don't want to do if either of the above failed
    '...

Exit_cmdDoTheThing:
    Screen.MousePointer = 0 'Default mouse pointer
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdDoTheThing:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_DoTheThing
End Sub
```

I don't want to repeat `Screen.MousePointer = 0` at every possible exit point so I figured a GoTo would serve as a decent shortcut since the `Exit_cmdDoTheThing` label was needed for error handling anyway.

Is this a valid use-case for a GoTo statement and if not is there some other way I can achieve the same result? I don't want a sudden [raptor attack](http://xkcd.com/292/) after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising a custom error can avoid the use of GoTo for subroutines with this error handling structure. This has the added benefit of making it clear to anyone reading the code that failure of certain functions to complete is considered an error in this situation, even if they do not raise an error upon failure.

```
Public Const cCustomErrNum = 9114

Private Sub cmdDoTheThing_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdDoTheThing

    Screen.MousePointer = 11 'Hourglass/Equivalent

    'Check all data is available to Do The Thing
    If Not MyModule.ThingIsDoable(Me.PrimaryKey) Then
        Err.Raise cCustomErrNum,"cmd_DoTheThing_Click()", _
            "Cannot Do The Thing, more preliminary things must be done first."
    End If

    'Try to Do The Thing (function returns false on failure)
    If Not MyModule.DoTheThing(Me.PrimaryKey) Then
        Err.Raise cCustomErrNum,"cmd_DoTheThing_Click()", _
            "Processing of The Thing failed."
    End If

    '...
    'Stuff here I don't want to do if either of the above failed
    '...

Exit_cmdDoTheThing:
    Screen.MousePointer = 0 'Default mouse pointer
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdDoTheThing:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_DoTheThing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

GoTo can be replaced by using a do-while block (which has a false condition and runs only once) and using 'Exit Do' wherever you want to skip the rest of the code.

So your code might now look like:

```
Private Sub cmdDoTheThing_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdDoTheThing

    Do
        Screen.MousePointer = 11 'Hourglass/Equivalent

        'Check all data is available to Do The Thing
        If Not MyModule.ThingIsDoable(Me.PrimaryKey) Then
            MsgBox "Cannot Do The Thing, more preliminary things must be done first."
            Exit Do
        End If

        'Try to Do The Thing (function returns false on failure)
        If Not MyModule.DoTheThing(Me.PrimaryKey) Then
            MsgBox "Processing of The Thing failed."
            Exit Do
        End If

        '...
        'Stuff here I don't want to do if either of the above failed
        '...
    Loop While FALSE

Exit_cmdDoTheThing:
    Screen.MousePointer = 0 'Default mouse pointer
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdDoTheThing:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_DoTheThing
End Sub
```

GoTo has to be used with real caution as it may make the code really complex after some iterations in the code. GoTo also allows you to do very weird/ugly things such as jump out of scope without actually going out of scope. With the do-while you ensure the flow of the code while maintaining the sanity and readability of the code.

Comment: In terms of structure and program flow this code is very similar to my given example, just with different syntax. With that in mind this would be a better answer if you could add some details about why the change in syntax is beneficial, what pitfalls does it avoid that I might hit with `GoTo`?

Comment: GoTo has to be used with real caution as it may make the code to be really complex after some iterations in the code. Also with GoTo, it allows you to do very weird/ugly things, such as jump out of scope without actually going out of scope, etc.
With the Do loop you ensure the flow of the code, maintain the sanity and readability of the code.

Comment: Good justification there but it's best to edit further information into your answer rather than just leaving it as a comment :)